# How do I stop Time Machine swamping my wifi network?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, time-machine, nas

I use Time Machine to back up my MacBook Air to a Synology DiskStation NAS. This works fine, but because of the layout of my home I have to connect to my home network wirelessly. This means that when Time Machine is running a backup, it can swamp my wifi and stop other devices getting a decent throughput. Is there anything I can do to fix this? Is it a question of throttling Time Machine on my Mac, or should I instead set priority rules on the router itself? Or take a different approach entirely?